# Firebase messaging data payload is null with Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using firebase-admin (version is 7.1.1) to send push notifications. In onMessageReceived(m: RemoteMessage) method the data and notification is null; and this method is not called when the application in background as it is normal behaviour of the system. I need to send data field every time. While sending request I do not have any error. It is how I am sending push-notification:

```
val builder = Message.builder()
                .setTopic(topic)
                .putData("type", "NEWS")
                .setNotification(
                     Notification.builder()
                       .setTitle(title)
                       .setBody(content)
                       .build()
                )

try {
      firebaseMessaging.send(builder.build())
} catch (e: Exception) {
      logger.error(e.message, e)
}
```

Comment: Do you have any error logs ?

Comment: No, there is no any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `.setNotification(..)` call. There should not be title and body for background notification.